# What is wrong with this python if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, fixed

I was making a function in python and used the following code:

```py
def multi(_conv, _pretty = False):
  result = []
  newResult = ""
  for a in range(len(_conv)):
    for i in range(len(data)):
      if (str(_conv[a]) == data[i][0]):
        result.append(data[i][1]

  if(bool(_pretty) == True):
    for i in range(len(result)):
      newResult += str(result[i])
      if(i != len(result) - 1):
        newResult += ", "
    return newResult
```

but for a reason that I cannot figure out, on the line `if(bool(_pretty) == True):` I am getting a syntax error on the colon. I have tried making sure that the spacing is correct, that there are no issues with parenthesis being open, and have also tried rewriting it to make sure I wasn't missing something, but nothing has worked. If somebody could help that would be great!

edit: Sorry! I did not realize that there was still an unclosed pair of parenthesis. That is my bad...

Comment: `if _pretty is True:` or simply `if _pretty:`

Comment: Missing `)` in previous line.

Comment: Ah, missed that :) Also, no space between `if` and `(`

Comment: By the way, that whole last `if` can be replaced with `new_result = ", ".join(result)`

Comment: The last if is used to see whether it is the last item in the list, and replacing it with `newResult = ", ".join(str(result))` puts a comma space in between every character in the list, instead of every item in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `)` in `result.append(data[i][1]` causing the interpreter to get a little confused.

---

Other issues...

You can use [`for`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) to iterate directly through the items in a list.

No parens are required on `if` conditions.

There's no need to cast `_pretty` nor compare it to True. It's enough that `_pretty` is [a true value](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_booleans.asp).

The result formatting can be done with [`join`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp).

```
  for c in _conv:
    for d in data:
      if str(c) == d[0]:
        result.append(d[1])

  if _pretty:
    return ", ".join(result)
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot, but I will note that using `join` does not give the desired output. `join` puts a ", " in between every character, where as I needed it to only be between items of a list when turned into a string.

Comment: @codeFerret `", ".join(result)` puts a `, ` between every item in `result`; `"; ".join(["foo", "bar"])` is a simple test. `result` only contains single characters. `d[1]` takes the second character of the string `d` in `data`. You're comparing the first character of `d` with all of `c` and then storing the second character of `d` in `result`.

Comment: The end goal is to have a string with a `, ` between every item in the original array. Using `join` puts a `, ` between every single character, even though there are several characters per item.

Comment: @codeFerret No, `join` is working fine. The problem is there is only a single character per item in `result`. You can check with `print(result)`. For example, if `data = ["abc"]` and you run `multi(["a", "a"], True)` then `result` will be `['b', 'b']`. [Try it](https://onecompiler.com/python/3wa8csx9x)

Comment: I see now that there has been a misunderstanding. The data is very specific and the code only works as expected when using the correct data. [Here is an example with the current data set.](https://onecompiler.com/python/3wac9jj5e) The code isn't super pretty bc I haven't gotten around to slimming it down yet, but it gives the desired result.

Comment: @codeFerret And once you convert the integers into strings, `join` works just fine. https://onecompiler.com/python/3wacntv2e

Comment: @codeFerret Note that you can convert a character to its Unicode code point with [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=ord#ord). https://onecompiler.com/python/3wacp9b4e